# .NET: How to exclude certain file name extensions when matching with a regex?

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I would like to write a regex which would strip certain file name extensions recursively (not all). The extensions to be stripped are **.ready**, **.done** and **.error**. The match should be made available through a single group item.

For instance:

```
HelloWorld.xml             --> HelloWorld.xml
Hello@World.xml.ready      --> Hello@World.xml
Yaba_Daba-Doo.aaa.orig     --> Yaba_Daba-Doo.aaa.orig
HelloWorld.xml.ready.error --> HelloWorld.xml
yogibear.xml.ready.done    --> yogibear.xml
HelloWorld.bbb.done        --> HelloWorld.bbb
Merry Chrismas.ready.yyy   --> Merry Chrismas.ready.yyy
```

So, I came up with the following simple regex - `^(.+)(?:\.(?:ready|done|error))*$`

Alas, it does not work as expected, because `(.+)` seems to be a greedy match.

P.S. Unfortunately, it could be any file name. The only thing that I want is trim any trailing `.ready`, `.done` and/or `.error`. I know I can do it in code, but I am interested in knowing how to tackle this with regex, since I have a feeling it is possible.

Comment: Insert .xml in your pattern and it should be fine. Something like `^(.+)\.xml(?:\.(?:ready|done|error))*$`

Comment: Is it always with regard to XML files?

Comment: Wouldn't be easier using System.IO.Path.GetExtension() or Split?

Comment: `.` means any character, and `+` means one or more.  So it's absorbing one or more of any character(which is the whole string).  We'll need more information on your file names to make a regex for them though.  If your filenames are like `HelloWorld`, with no underscores and only letters in them, than you can replace your `(.+)` with `(\w+)`.

Comment: Unfortunately, it could be any file name. The only thing that I want is trim any trailing `.ready`, `.done` and/or `.error`. I know I can do it in code, but I am interested in knowing how to tackle this with regex, since I have a feeling it is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems too easy so something must be wrong, but i am going to post my solution anyway.
You only need to replace the `+` in the first group `(.+)` with a the non-greedy version `+?`.
The final regular expression becomes this one: `^(.+?)(?:\.(?:ready|done|error))*$`

And you can try it with this code:

```
string strRegex = @"^(.+?)(?:\.(?:ready|done|error))*$";
RegexOptions myRegexOptions = RegexOptions.None;
Regex myRegex = new Regex(strRegex, myRegexOptions);
string strTargetString = @"Merry Chrismas.ready.yyy";
string strReplace = @"${1}";

return myRegex.Replace(strTargetString, strReplace);
```

Comment: This is precisely what I was looking for. I knew I need non greedy match, just could not figure out how to specify it. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the best option here is to first match the list of files, then strip the unwanted file extensions like so:

```
Regex regex = new Regex(@"\.(ready|done|error)$", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
fileNames = fileNames.Select(f => regex.Replace(f, "")).ToList();
```

I just don't see the point of trying to match the start of the string.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this**

```
String[] test ={ "HelloWorld.xml", "HelloWorld.xml.ready", "HelloWorld.xml.orig", "HelloWorld.xml.ready.error", "HelloWorld.xml.ready.done", "HelloWorld.bbb.done", "HelloWorld.ready.yyy" };
var query = test.ToArray().Where(c => Regex.IsMatch(c,"(?:error|done|ready)$"));
foreach (String field in query)
{
    Console.WriteLine(field);
}
```